# difference between inbound and outbound web service

Tags: web-services, wsdl

What is the difference between inbound and outbound web service?
In inbound I must consuming a wsdl? or should I expose my service?

Is there a difference between the type of communication? Synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Inbound webservice is something which your website will consume. There could be webservices published by some other 3rd party tool. You can import that webservice and use that to call methods from 3rd party tool.

Oubound Webservice is something that you publish from your server and 3rd party tools consume it to get data/record from your server.

I hope that made some sense.

Answer (score 8):

Its a lot of confusion let me clarify in an easy way.

**here we go:**

```
Client(our computer A) ----request------> 3rd party(service provider B)
                       <---response------
```

***Explanation:***

**From A point of you its OutBound Service, from B point of you is Inbound**

```
Client(our computer A) <----request------ 3rd party(service provider B)
                       ---response------>
```

***Explanation:***
**From A point of you its InBound Service, from B point of you is OutBound**

Therefore:

**InBound:** It accepts the request and processing it. **(Travelling towards)**

**OutBound:** when it hit the other 3rd party service. **(Travelling away)**

Comment: it helps me to understand the concept! thank you for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation#1:

> Inbound / Call-In: - Receiving Request
>
> Outbound / Call-Out: - Sending Response
>
> Mid Server - Acts as interface between SN and a outer network

### Explanation#2:

**Inbound means** that other applications make calls to ServiceNow's REST API to get information from SN, or create/update records.

**Outbound means** that ServiceNow makes calls to other applications' REST API to get information from the other application or create/update records.

### Explanation#3:

inbound is basically when some other tool hits your instance(wsdl) with a payload and you process it and acknowledge it. EG, if an incident gets created in a third party tool then an incident gets created in a service now . Here we accept the request and process it.

When we hit any other tool then its outbound. EG exactly opposite to the above eg, when an incident gets created in Service now, a similar incident should get created on the other tool. Here we prepare the payload and hit the other tool's wsdl.

**You can get videos here:**

[Integration Best Practices - Inbound Web Service - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EhxgEECd7mQ)

[Integration Best Practices - Outbound Web Service - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeeDW_iRM8k)

**Resource Link:** https://community.servicenow.com/thread/178997